# Provider.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: store.getState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I cant fixt this error, please help me to fix it. when I am going to run my reactApp into my local-host then in the console I get lot o error but my terminal does not get any error.
In this App I am using redux,react-redux,axios,thunk from packegemanager **

here is my code

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

*App.js*

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h3>Practice redux</h3>
     <TodosApp />
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

*store.js*

```
import todosReducer from './component/todo/todoReducer'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(todosReducer,thunk)
export default store
```

*actiontype.js*

```
export const GET_REQUEST_SUCCESS = 'GET_REQUEST_SUCCESS'
export const GET_REQUEST_FAILD = 'GET_REQUEST_FAILD'
```

*actionCreator.js*

```
const initialState = {
    isLoading : false,
    todo :[],
    error: null
}



const todosReducer = (state= initialState,action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_REQUEST_LOADING:
            
            return{
                ...state,
                isLoading:true
            }
    
            case GET_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
            
            return{
                ...state,
               todo : action.payload,
               isLoading :false,
               error: null
            }

            case GET_REQUEST_FAILD:
            
            return{
                ...state,
                error: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default todosReducer
```

*todoReducer*

```
const initialState = {
    isLoading : false,
    todo :[],
    error: null
}



const todosReducer = (state= initialState,action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_REQUEST_LOADING:
            
            return{
                ...state,
                isLoading:true
            }
    
            case GET_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
            
            return{
                ...state,
               todo : action.payload,
               isLoading :false,
               error: null
            }

            case GET_REQUEST_FAILD:
            
            return{
                ...state,
                error: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default todosReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

export const store = createStore(countReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
thunk should go through middleware.

Comment: Thank you so much  mam. It was my small mistake that not to find it then. But now I found my error with the help of your suggestion.